# How do we use the ProgID column in the File Associations settings?

Tags: deployment, clickonce, progid

I'm deploying my application using *ClickOnce*.

I want to register a file association but I can't manage to make it work: What should I use as *ProgID* in the *File Associations* section of the *Publish Options*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a name that uniquely identifies the file type. So a description might be "Document created with Microsoft Word" and the ProgID might be "Word". If your app name is short, you can just put that in there. If your app name isn't short, put in some abbreviation of it.

Answer (score 3):

Some examples from the registry subkeys
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\ ~ \OpenWithProgids`:

- **.bmp** - `Paint.Picture`
- **.csproj** - `VisualStudio.Launcher.csproj.15.0`
- **.csv** - `Excel.CSV`
- **.docx** - `Word.Document.12`
- **.mp4** - `WMP11.AssocFile.MP4`