# What should I enter in the ProgID field in the file associations dialog in VS2010?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I want my program to be associated with a custom file type so that clicking on a file of that type will open it with my program.

I've seen I can do that by: Properties->Publish->Options->File associations. But I don't know what I should enter as ProgID.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProgID) it seems it's some long number (is there a specific way of choosing it?). From an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2684900/939213) it seems it's just anything I want.

Comment: this question on SO should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c-sharp

Comment: @KamilLach Thanks. But I saw that question before posting mine. It doesn't refer to the ProgID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just fire up regedit.exe and see how other programs do it.  The progids are listed in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  The (Default) value of a filename extension key in the list you see there is the progid associated with the extension.  Some common samples:

- .dll = "dllfile"
- .exe = "exefile"
- .ico = "icofile"
- .txt = "txtfile"

You see the pattern.  It isn't *required* that it looks like this, just a convention.  "YourCompany.YourFileType" is fine as well with the advantages of it being more descriptive and avoiding name collisions.