# What is the ProgID when a associating a file extension?

Tags: c#, file-extension, progid

[picture from the setting box in projekt properties -> publish (sorry for german)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED0mS.png)

I am trying to get a file extension associated with my programm. What is the ProgID? Is the extension associated once the programm is started or does i need to be install properly (I am trying to just use the .exe without a install wizard).

Comment: It is whatever you want it to be, "testfile" would be logical choice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10271261/17034

Comment: Thank you.  Can you answer the other part as well please? (Is the extension associated once the programm is started or does i need to be install properly (I am trying to just use the .exe without a install wizard).)

Comment: It is not automagic.  You have to write to the registry and that is only possible when you got UAC elevation.  You normally get *one* chance for that, when your user runs your installer.

Comment: can i write to the registry everytime (or at least when it is dedected that it has not already been written to). If yes how would i do that.