# Setting the icon for a document associated with an exe in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, icons, document

Setting the icon for an application in Visual Studio is fairly straightforward now. But, is it possible to set a *different* icon for files (documents) associated with your exe?

I remember it being not that difficult on the Mac (years ago). Does anybody know the secret for setting a specific icon for a document that is different than for the application that it is associated with in Windows via Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I stumbled upon the answer...

In Visual Studio 2010...

Right click on the project...

Select 'Publish' last vertical tab on the left.

Select the Options button (last of four buttons on the right).

Select 'File Associations'...

There you can select the Icon. Not exactly sure what ProgID is... I'll post, again, when I find out more. And some info about the ProgID is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681604/how-do-we-use-the-progid-column-in-the-file-associations-settings/2684900#2684900). The 'short answer is' pretty much anything you want.